# Spring JDBCTemplate Execute Not Throwing Exceptions

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbctemplate

I've got a spring application, one of it's functions is to be able to take any piece of SQL and run it, a poller polls a folder for a trigger file containing the location of a SQL file, the application then reads the SQL file and places contents into the 'sqlquery' message header.

Problem we seem to have is that exceptions aren't being thrown when the SQL fails.

```
    try
    {
        if ((msg.getHeaders().containsKey("sqlQuery"))&&(!"".equals(msg.getHeaders().get("sqlQuery"))))
        {
            _log.debug("Executing: " + msg.getHeaders().get("sqlQuery"), UID);
            jdbcTemplate.execute((String) msg.getHeaders().get("sqlQuery"));
            _log.info("Query executed successfully.", UID);
        }

        result = "S";
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        _log.error(ex, ex, UID);
    }
```

JDBC Drivers is Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.2, connecting to a SQL Server 2014 database.

I've tried running this with a simple 'Select 1/0' which would obviously throw a divide by zero error, but we get a successful response.

```
2018-07-19 16:36:01,738|org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils|sqlFileChannelTaskExecutor-6|DEBUG|Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2018-07-19 16:36:01,738|org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler|sqlFileChannelTaskExecutor-6|DEBUG|org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler@c6d1b7 received message: GenericMessage [payload={UPDATED=1}, headers={UID=MCTest, errorChannel=logSqlErrorChannel, id=318f54b8-2889-22af-1009-e191550c75eb, sqlQuery=Select 1/0, timestamp=1532014561738}]
2018-07-19 16:36:01,738|org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory|sqlFileChannelTaskExecutor-6|DEBUG|Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'integrationEvaluationContext'
2018-07-19 16:36:01,738|org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory|sqlFileChannelTaskExecutor-6|DEBUG|Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'integrationConversionService'
2018-07-19 16:36:01,738|MCTest|sqlFileChannelTaskExecutor-6|DEBUG|SQL Step Started
2018-07-19 16:37:16,926|MCTest|sqlFileChannelTaskExecutor-6|DEBUG|Executing: Select 1/0
2018-07-19 16:37:22,530|org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate|sqlFileChannelTaskExecutor-6|DEBUG|Executing SQL statement [Select 1/0]
2018-07-19 16:37:28,278|org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils|sqlFileChannelTaskExecutor-6|DEBUG|Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2018-07-19 16:37:28,278|org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource|sqlFileChannelTaskExecutor-6|DEBUG|Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:sqlserver://<Server>;databaseName=<Database]
2018-07-19 16:37:33,069|org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils|sqlFileChannelTaskExecutor-6|DEBUG|Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2018-07-19 16:37:33,069|MCTest|sqlFileChannelTaskExecutor-6|INFO |Query executed successfully.
```

Can anyone help explain why exceptions aren't getting captured/thrown?

Answer (score 0):

share you query.. and use `catch (ArithmeticException ae)` where as if you have issues in understanding the 1/0  [ArithmeticException](http://catch%20(ArithmeticException%20ae)).

hope it will work.